# Get json file locally using chrome for iOS

Tags: jquery, json

What are the methods or approaches that I should use in order for me to get data from JSON file locally.

`$.getJSON` works fine in firefox, however chrome doesn't work unless you run on localhost.

I want to run it properly in chrome(Since android uses chrome) without using localhost servers such as xampp, and also run it on safari(iOS uses safari).

I'll run this on android and iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi Jed I guess you need to use [JSONP](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.getJSON/index.html).

Also, here's another [link](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) about JSONP.

I hope this helps.